# M2.2.3 : How can I create a Category Attribute in the global scope?

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, scope

I'm trying to create a global scoped category attribute, but it always seem to be scoped on store-level. I've got this:

```
$categorySetup->addAttribute(
    $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(Category::ENTITY),
    CategoryMetaInterface::CATEGORY_CODE,
    [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Category Code',
        'input' => 'text',
        'unique' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    ]
);
```

This creates the attribute, but it does not set it's scope to GLOBAL; if I look into `catalog_eav_attribute`, the `is_global`-column is set to 0, but it should be 1. Even if I add:

```
$categorySetup->updateAttribute(
    Category::ENTITY,
    CategoryMetaInterface::CATEGORY_CODE,
    'global',
    ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL
);
```

The scope is not adjusted. I already tried changing `global` to `is_global`, but with no luck. Any thoughts on this?

Another strange issue: also the setting of `visible => true/false` does not seem to have any effect when it comes to categories. Is the `catalog_eav_attribute`-table properly populated when it comes to category attributes?

**UPDATE:** Found the issue. It's almost too embarrassing to say but there was in fact another update script that also tried to create this attribute with the older settings (refactoring gone wrong). Removing this old (not-so-dead) code solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have included `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface` as I can see your setting scope `ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL` and not like

`'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL` as in the core modules.

Comment: Yes, i did this.

Comment: @GielBerkers Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7176 , this might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using full scope specification `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL` 
sample attribute code

`$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'call_for_price', [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Call for Price?',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'visible' => true,
                'default' => 0,
                'required' => false,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'group' => 'General',
            ]);`

Comment: This should not make a difference, because it's a PHP constant. You could also use `'global' => '1'` to get the same result. But nevertheless, tried it, zero result.

Answer (score 0):

It will not update if attribute has been previously created so add 
 `$eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'attribute_code');` before addAttribute function